# display child divs outside parent even if their markup is inside jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i have dynamic divs and they have the an absolut position an are positioned in a div. I want do display first of all the divs after parent next to each other, but they must to be a part of parent.I am using draggable and resizable soo you can change the position and resize the div.After that you can save all and next time you will have that div with the saved position. Thats why i need the div inside of parent.

**Here is my code:**

```js
$('#box').draggable();
$('#box0').draggable();

$('#box').resizable();
$('#box0').resizable();
```

```css
#container {
    
    height: 250px;
    border: 5px dotted #292929;        
    }
#box {
    float:left;
    width:100px;
    height:75px;
    padding:15px;
    margin-right:5px;
    background:rgb(107, 193, 243);
}

#box0 {
    float:left;
    width:100px;
    height:75px;
    padding:15px;
    margin-right:5px;
    background:rgb(118, 136, 240);
    cursor:move;
    
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<div id="container">
           <div id="box">
            1. BOX
            <p id="top"></p>
            <p id="left"></p>  
            <p id="height"></p>
            <p id="width"></p>          
        </div>

        <div id="box0"> 
            2. BOX
            <p id="top"></p>
            <p id="left"></p>
            <p id="height"></p>
            <p id="width"></p>
        </div>
    </div>
```

**And here is what i need:**

[image]

Comment: What do you want to be implemented, as your draggable function is working

Comment: @Sonia i have some dynamic divs that are part of container.  I want to display the divs after container soo that you can move them to tem parent and there to place where you want. After that you can save all and next time you will have that div with the saved position. How can i display this div after container next to another ?

Comment: why don't you place `<div id="box">` outside the container ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The drag effect will change `top` and `left` values.

To get your result, add a default `top` value.

I did `260px`. 200 for the container height 5 for the container border and an extra 5 for space.

Hope this helps :)

```js
$('#box').draggable();
$('#box0').draggable();

$('#box').resizable();
$('#box0').resizable();
```

```css
#container {
  height: 250px;
  border: 5px dotted #292929;
}

#box {
  float: left;
  width: 100px;
  height: 75px;
  padding: 15px;
  margin-right: 5px;
  background: rgb(107, 193, 243);
  top: 260px;
}

#box0 {
  float: left;
  width: 100px;
  height: 75px;
  padding: 15px;
  margin-right: 5px;
  background: rgb(118, 136, 240);
  cursor: move;
  top: 260px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<div id="container">
  <div id="box">
    1. BOX
    <p id="top"></p>
    <p id="left"></p>
    <p id="height"></p>
    <p id="width"></p>
  </div>

  <div id="box0">
    2. BOX
    <p id="top"></p>
    <p id="left"></p>
    <p id="height"></p>
    <p id="width"></p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thx, but this is not what i am looking for. I have it dynamic thats meean more then 2  it means 20-25 and it must to be  like row. Thats why ask for Jquery. If you understand what i mean.

Comment: No i dont get whats wrong. Its the image you added. Can you specify what it should look like with more

Comment: i have a database there i save all value, after that i display it soo after displaying i will have another top,left,width and height.

Comment: Can you provide an example. I am able to help you with what ever you need, but i kind of need examples to debbug on it

Comment: look here : http://myworkbook.nl/try
there you can move box3 and box4 i want it next to each

Comment: why both have ``left`` at 0? you hardcoded that value?

Comment: this is default because they are outside of container.thats why i need to do it with jquery.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168743/discussion-between-gerardo-blanco-and-cristian-cnnu).

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the top property to a value `>100%`, let me know if it helps

```js
/*$('#box').draggable();
$('#box0').draggable();

$('#box').resizable();
$('#box0').resizable();*/

$('.inner-box').draggable();
$('.inner-box').resizable();
```

```css
#container {
    
    height: 250px;
    border: 5px dotted #292929;        
    }
#box {
    float:left;
    width:100px;
    height:75px;
    padding:15px;
    margin-right:5px;
    background:rgb(107, 193, 243);
}

#box0 {
    float:left;
    width:100px;
    height:75px;
    padding:15px;
    margin-right:5px;
    background:rgb(118, 136, 240);
    cursor:move;
}

.inner-box{
  top: 105%;
  
  float:left;
    width:100px;
    height:75px;
    padding:15px;
    margin-right:5px;
    background: red
    
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<div id="container">
           <div class="inner-box" id="box">
            1. BOX
            <p id="top"></p>
            <p id="left"></p>  
            <p id="height"></p>
            <p id="width"></p>          
        </div>

        <div class="inner-box" id="box0"> 
            2. BOX
            <p id="top"></p>
            <p id="left"></p>
            <p id="height"></p>
            <p id="width"></p>
        </div>
        <div class="inner-box"> 
            2. BOX
            <p id="top"></p>
            <p id="left"></p>
            <p id="height"></p>
            <p id="width"></p>
        </div>
        <div class="inner-box"> 
            2. BOX
            <p id="top"></p>
            <p id="left"></p>
            <p id="height"></p>
            <p id="width"></p>
        </div>
        <div class="inner-box"> 
            2. BOX
            <p id="top"></p>
            <p id="left"></p>
            <p id="height"></p>
            <p id="width"></p>
        </div>
        <div class="inner-box"> 
            2. BOX
            <p id="top"></p>
            <p id="left"></p>
            <p id="height"></p>
            <p id="width"></p>
        </div>
        <div class="inner-box"> 
            2. BOX
            <p id="top"></p>
            <p id="left"></p>
            <p id="height"></p>
            <p id="width"></p>
        </div>
        <div class="inner-box"> 
            2. BOX
            <p id="top"></p>
            <p id="left"></p>
            <p id="height"></p>
            <p id="width"></p>
        </div>
        
    </div>
```

Comment: thx for it, but is not what i am looking for. Take a look here : http://myworkbook.nl/try mybe you will understand it better.

Comment: @CristianCănănău then I strongly advice you to include what you *are* looking for :), we can't guess your goals beyond what you describe in your post,which I think boiled down to *display child divs outside parent even if their markup is inside*

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would've done it. You can extend this example to whatever you want

```js
var numberOfBoxes = 5;
function draw(){
$("#container").html("");
for(let i=0; i<numberOfBoxes; i++){

 
  $("#container").append(`<div class="${(i+1) %2 === 0 ? 'box' : 'boxe'}" id="box-${i+1}">
            ${i+1}. BOX
            <p id="top"></p>
            <p id="left"></p>  
            <p id="height"></p>
            <p id="width"></p>          
        </div>`)
        
         $(`#box-${i+1}`).draggable();
          $(`#box-${i+1}`).resizable();
}
}
draw();
function addBox(){
numberOfBoxes++;
draw();
}
```

```css
#container {
    
    height: 250px;
    border: 5px dotted #292929;        
    }
.box {
    float:left;
    width:100px;
    height:75px;
    padding:15px;
    margin-right:5px;
    top: 110%;
    background:rgb(107, 193, 243);
}
.btn{
  padding : 10px;
  margin : 10px;
}

.boxe {
    float:left;
    position:relative;
    width:100px;
    height:75px;
    padding:15px;
     top: 110%;
    margin-right:5px;
    background:rgb(118, 136, 240);
    cursor:move;
    
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<button onclick="addBox()" class="btn">Add Box</button>
<div id="container">

 </div>
```

Comment: thx but as i said  i save the value and after that i call them from databse thats mean that i have allrady all boxes and i want to display them after container net to each other.

Comment: what value ? number of boxes ?

Comment: it different that why i said dynamic div. I want to have it like if the boxes have value 0 like height,width,left,top then give them the position close to each other and if not then give them the position that is from database

Comment: Ohk. sorry for misunderstanding

Comment: look here :  http://myworkbook.nl/try  you will understand what i mean, i have there box3 and box4. and thx for your help.